# .replace isn't updating variable value resulting in incorrect write to an output file

Tags: java

This is a portion of a mab libs game that is reading in a template from one file and then using PrintStream to send out the game results to another wherever a tag in the template such as  or  exists, the user is prompted to give a value to replace it. The issue that I'm having right now is that the tags with a "-" are not being replaced. One of the requirements is that all "-" be converted to spaces instead so I have some code to do so. As a result of the code that checks for a "-", the template output where tags contain "-" don't get changed to the user input. If I remove the code that checks for -, It works fine but the user prompt cant include a -.

```
                        while (each.hasNext()) {
                            String word = each.next();

                            if (word.contains("<")) {
                                int start = word.indexOf("<");
                                int end = word.indexOf(">");
                                // word between <>
                                String x = word.substring(start + 1, end);
                                // checks
                                if (x.contains("-")) {
                                    x = x.replace("-", " ");
                                }
                                // if tag starts with a vowel, make "an";
                                if (vowelCheck(x) == true) {
                                    preInput = "an";
                                }
                                System.out.println("please enter " + preInput + " " + x + ":");
                                String lib = userInput.nextLine();
                                // maybe make it not word
                                word = word.replace(x, lib);
                                // edit not holding changed text ,lib is correct though
                                output.print(word);
                            } else {
                                // normal words in lines with tags
                                output.print(word + " ");
                            }
                        }
```

I used some print statements to check var values and word = word.replace(x, lib) doesn't seem to be getting updated from the x value as I expected it to, Think that might be where the issue is occurring but haven't been able to get passed that.

I spent a long time trying to figure this out and I'm totally stuck! All help is greatly appreciated

data:

input file looks something like this:

```
<Male-Name> has announced that his <adjective>
clothing store in the heart of downtown <CITY> is having
a/an <adjective> sale of all merchandise, including
<unusual-adjective> suits and slightly irregular <plural-noun>
available. Men's cable-knit <plural-noun> , only $15.99.
Hand-woven Italian <plural-noun> , 1/2-price. Double-
breasted cashmere <plural-noun> , $50.00. Genuine imported
<Color!> <adjective> shoes, <Exciting-adjective> handerchiefs,
and women's embroidered <plural-noun> , all at rock-bottom prices.
This is a chance to get some really <Interesting-Adjective> bargains.
```

BAD OUTPUT:

```
<Male-Name>has announced that his <flat>
clothing store in the heart of downtown <LA>is having 
a/an <fast>sale of all merchandise, including 
<unusual-adjective>suits and slightly irregular <plural-noun>
available. Men's cable-knit <plural-noun>, only $15.99. 
Hand-woven Italian <plural-noun>, 1/2-price. Double- 
breasted cashmere <plural-noun>, $50.00. Genuine imported 
<blue><small>shoes, <Exciting-adjective>handerchiefs, 
and women's embroidered <plural-noun>, all at rock-bottom prices. 
This is a chance to get some really <Interesting-Adjective>bargains.
```

All  should be replaced just like the rest.

Comment: it should work https://ideone.com/DWxZXS. My first guess will be the code doesnt go inside the if condition with contains()

Comment: perhaps because not all words contain "<"? ideone is cool.

Comment: Can you add some sample data?  Even if you're reading it from file right now, the best thing for getting help here would be to just put some sample data in as a string.

Comment: added some more details on what getting outputted. @Steve, The code does get called (passes into the contains if statement). I put print statements in all the loops when debugging, they all got called.

Comment: So did my answer solve your problem?  It should have.

Comment: it did yes! sorry totally forgot to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you have dashes in a replacement tag, you're replacing the dashes with spaces, but then you're trying to find that modified version of the string in the input text to replace it with the user's input value.  Since you changed the value after you pulled it out of the text, it is no longer going to match the text.

What you can do is save off the original value and use that to find/replace the user's input into the original text.

```
int start = word.indexOf("<");
int end = word.indexOf(">");
// word between <>
String x = word.substring(start + 1, end);
String origX = x;  // <- MAKE A COPY OF THE TAG STRING
// checks
if (x.contains("-")) {
    x = x.replace("-", " ");
}
String preInput = "";
System.out.println("please enter " + preInput + " " + x + ":");
String lib = userInput.nextLine();
// maybe make it not word
word = word.replace(origX, lib);  // <- USE THE COPY YOU MADE EARLIER TO DO THE FIND/REPLACE
// edit not holding changed text ,lib is correct though
System.out.println(word);
```